# How to decode this binary message?

Tags: binary, cryptography, translate

When my best friend wrote his yearbook message to me in 5-bit binary, I didn't the slightest idea of how to translate it.  Can anyone please tell me what he could have possibly said?

00001 01010 01101 00000 10001 11000      01010 10010 00111 00000 10001 00011. 
-01001 00000 01010 00100 01100 00111 00000 00110 10010!

Comment: Which encoding and endianness?

Comment: It says "Be sure to drink your Ovaltine." At least, that's what my decoder pin gave me...

Comment: She obviously doesn't know. Neither do I. 0 and 1 are in there, so not ascii. I was thinking 5 bit bcd with an 'a=1' type code, but that gives ajm or bkn as the first 3, and it don't make sense.

Comment: I vote gibberish, or some really odd, nonstandard encoding.

Comment: [ITA1 and ITA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_binary_codes#Five-bit_binary_codes) do not seem to work, either.

Comment: as integers it is 1,10,13,0,17,24,10,18,7,0,17,3(.),(-)9,0,10,4,12,7,0,6,18(!)

Comment: 5 bit bcd with a=1 gives what initially looks like gibberish, though with a bit of playing around, you can pull out the phrase 
BINARY IS HARD. -JAKE MHAGS!, where MHAGS is presumably a misspelling of Jake's last name.
Note that the educated guessing involved fixing numerous typos, inserting spaces, etc.
B K N A R Y K S H A R D J A K E M H A G S

Comment: @CMP it were integers already. :) you mean **decimal** integers.

Comment: Thats it!. Write an answer. But your translation is for a=0.

Comment: @Sysyphus Well done; looks like he used "`K`" instead of "`I`". Not sure about the last name, maybe @TheGirlCalledMoo can help?

Answer (score 6):

5 bit bcd with a=0 gives what initially looks like gibberish, though with a bit of playing around, you can pull out the phrase BINARY IS HARD. -JAKE MHAGS!, where MHAGS is presumably a misspelling of Jake's last name. Note that the educated guessing involved fixing numerous typos, inserting spaces, etc.
`B K N A R Y K S H A R D J A K E M H A G S`

Now in answer form instead of as a comment.

Comment: Alternatively, if one assumes it's an anagram, rather than him having made typos, it could decode to something like `Shy Handbag Jerks! -Markka`, which I think is a much more interesting answer ;).

Comment: My favorite is "Bad Hag Shanks Jerky Mark"